# jQuery Autocomplete one input, then populate other relevant inputs?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the [Formidable Pro](http://formidablepro.com/) WordPress plugin to create editable forms. Each form has several different "Contact Info" areas (in the below picture, one such area is "General Contractor", and another one is "Mechanical Engineer"), and each area has several inputs.

What I'm looking to create:

1. Enter first few letters of persons name in "Contact" input
2. Select a name from resulting Autocomplete drop-down
3. Populate nearby fields with Contact's respective information (Company, Email, Phone, Fax, Tax ID, and Address)

The first image below shows two of the "Contact Info" areas (the first of which I drew in each input's ID). The second image shows how each Contact's information is stored in a MySQL table.

So are there any Autocomplete WordPress or jQuery plugins that can help me accomplish this, and if so, how would I go about implementing this feature?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing for the drop-downs you're using dynamic fields? Replace these with Lookup fields and then you can automatically populate values of other fields like so:

For each field you want auto-populated, go into the field settings and check the option 'Dynamically retrieve the value from a Lookup field'. Then, for the 'Get value from' options, you'll need to select the form and field you want to Get the data from. Then, for the 'Watch Lookup fields' option you'll need to select the lookup field (which will be your 'Contact' input that users are typing into).